# Is the trivial sheaf fine?

Tags: differential-topology, sheaf-theory

A sheaf is called fine if basically it has partition of unit for endomorphisms. That is, if $P:E \rightarrow M$ is a sheaf, then $P$ is called fine if for for every locally finite open cover $\{U_{i}\}_{i \in I}$, with $U_{i} \subsetneq M$,  $\bigcup\limits_{i \in I} U_{i} = M$ there exists sheaf endomorphisms $\psi_{i} :M \rightarrow M$  such that $Support(\psi_i) \subseteq U_{i}$ and $\Sigma_{i} \psi_i = 1$

The trivial sheaf is the function

\begin{gather*}P:M\times T \rightarrow M  \\ (m,t)\rightarrow\ m \end{gather*}

with $M$ a topological space, $T$ an $A$-module with the discrete topology and the space étale $M \times T$ with the product topology.

I was wondering if the trivial sheaf is fine, in all cases, in some cases or what suffices so that it's fine.

Comment: My first intuition was, since I just needed to prove it for any topological space, take $M=$ any differential manifold and given a covering $\{U_{i}\}$ take the usual partition of unit $f_{i}: U_{i} \rightarrow \mathbb R$ $f_{i} \in C^\infty$ define

\begin{gather*}\overline{f_{i}}: M \times \mathbb R \rightarrow M \times \mathbb R 
\\
(m;\lambda) \rightarrow (m;\lambda f_{i}(m))\end{gather*}

where the second $\mathbb R$ has the discrete topology (because of the definition of trivial sheaf).

Comment: I don't see why your map $\overline{f_i}$ is continuous if $\mathbb{R}$ is given the discrete topology. It would be the case if $f_i$ was locally constant, but it is not. In fact, the constant sheaf is not fine in general. If you know cohomology, the constant sheaf is not even acyclic since its cohomology give the cohomology of the space.

Comment: What is the definition of sheaf you are using?

Comment: I wrote it. The trivial sheaf is the function, etc...